# Larger Photo From Image_Capture Intent

Tags: android, xamarin.android

The images the camera is taking are 324 x 190.  How can I take larger photos using android intent?  Current code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == 0)
        {
            var settings = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            var assetID = settings.GetString("unit", null);
            var store = settings.GetString("store", null);
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            var date1 = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            var time1 = dt.ToString("HH:mm");

            Bitmap bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

                inst.saveImage(base64String, store, assetID, date1, time1);
            }

        }

    }
```

inst.saveImage... is a Web Method that saves the image to a SQL Server Database.

Then when I run a select on that table to display the image in a browser in my ASP.net project using

```
"data:image/png;base64," + base64 string from SQL,
```

it is only a 324 x 190 image. I need either for it to take a larger photo from the intent or a way to display it larger using the data url in ASP.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a full size image from the IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, you need to use:

```
intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, contentResolverUri);
```

Something like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put (MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Title, title);
values.Put (MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Description, description);
Uri uri = ContentResolver.Insert (MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, values);

intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uri);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE